# Error: illegal use of this type as an expression. list in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

i m trying to make a project that requires the use of list.i cant seem to get it to work.
following is my code:

```
ref class MyClass2
{
    public:
        int x;
        String^ str;
}
List<MyClass2> lst =gcnew List<MyClass2>(); //here is the error
```

I am working in visual studio 2008.

Comment: This is C++/CLI which is an important distinction, and should use the C++-CLI tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this (note the *three total* `^` used):

```
List<MyClass2^>^ lst =gcnew List<MyClass2^>();
```

This is because `MyClass2` is a reference type and can only be used with `MyClass2^` and allocated with `gcnew` (just like `List`).

Thus you have a reference to a `List` that can contain references to `MyClass2`.

Then, to add items:

```
MyClass2^ mc = gcnew MyClass2();
mc->x = 2; //Set values
lst->Add(mc);
```

Comment: @user3508140 if you are new to C++/CLI, there are a lot of new/different things going on.

Comment: Sorry. I was too early to comment. The error is still there. Error: "Generic type argument for T cannot be MyClass2".

Comment: @user3508140 and you have all three `^`s (two before the `=` and one after?)

Comment: @user3508140 try pasting the exact line I have. It builds with your class definition when I put it in a project.

Comment: Well it worked for a moment. There's another error now. I have an object 'p' of MyClass2. When i try to add 'x' and 'str' using lst.Add(p)... It gives me an error c2228: left of '.add' must have class/struct/union.

Comment: @user3508140 make sure `lst` is in scope of where you have that `Add` call. But sounds like that could be a new question.

Comment: I'll post it as a new question. Thank you for your help. :D

Comment: lst-> Add not lst.Add

Answer (score 0):

`gcnew` returns a *reference*. You can't just assign it to an object. Also, you are storing references, not objects. Thus, just do this:

```
List<MyClass2^>^ lst = gcnew List<MyClass2^>(); //note what I'm assigning to
```

Similarly, with standard `new` you have to use pointers.

Comment: the error still stays.anything else that i can try?

Comment: The edited one worked. I should have realized my mistake earlier. Thank you for helping. :D

Comment: @user3508140 Found it after spinning up my IDE, sorry for the delay

Comment: Sorry. I was to early to comment. I get this error. Error: "Generic type argument for T cannot be MyClass2". Any ideas?

Comment: @user3508140 You are missing the ^ at the end of your argument most likely.

Comment: That worked. I have another error now. Please refer to my comment to crashmstr's post. Thank you for your help. :)